# Regression by group and extract studentized.residuals and predicted values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to run the following linear model : Y ~ X1 + X2 on a dataset where I need this model to run by group=location. My objective is to get my original dataset with 2 additional columns containing "predicted values" and "studentized_residuals".
I tried diffent codes, and the one below is the one that gave me some good outputs, but not for all the groups, it seems to work for the 1st group only :

```
library("tidyverse")
library(broom)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
df$Y <- as.numeric(df$Y)
df$X1 <- as.factor(df$X1)
df$X2 <- as.factor(df$X2)

by_group <- group_by(df, location)
model <- do(by_group, augment(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = .)))
df$predicted <- model$.fitted
df$stud_resids <- model$.std.resid
```

My dataset looks like :

```
Location    Y   X1  X2
1           32  1   1
1           44  1   2
1           58  1   3
1           76  2   1
1           73  2   2
1           37  2   3
1           52  3   1
1           78  3   2
1           60  3   3
2           93  1   1
2           78  1   2
2           25  1   3
2           97  2   1
2           85  2   2
2           60  2   3
2           70  3   1
2           62  3   2
2           95  3   3
```

I hope someone can help me !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hello @Betty888 and welcome to Stack Overflow! I think we'll be able to help with this, but it'll require you're providing some data. Can you provide `dput()` of your df?

Comment: Your `df` contains only one column: `Location`?

Comment: Hi , I don't know how to add my table ...

Comment: Yes, I have 1 column Location containing several levels and I need to run my lm by location level

Comment: To be clear about the the shape of your `dataset`, @Betty88: Is it a table with four column headings: Location, Y, X1, and X2, each then with values beneath?

Comment: Yes this is roughly how my dataset looks

Comment: Exact : 4 columns with headers "Location" , "Y" , "X1", "X2"

Answer (score 0):

@Betty888, I cannot seem to reproduce the problem you're encountering. Here's what I've come up with:

```
Location <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Y <- c(32, 44, 58, 76, 73, 37, 52, 78, 60, 93, 78, 25, 97, 85, 60, 70, 62, 95)
X1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
X2 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

df  <- data.frame(Location, Y, X1, X2)
df$Y <- as.numeric(df$Y)
df$X1 <- as.factor(df$X1)
df$X2 <- as.factor(df$X2)

by_group <- group_by(df, Location)
model <- do(by_group, augment(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = .)))

df$predicted <- model$.fitted
df$stud_resids <- model$.std.resid

print(df)
```

And this yields (I'm working in Rmarkdown to PDF):

[image]

So if I understand you correctly, this *is* your desired result. But if I'm missing something please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !
My target is to get Stud.resid and Precited values from runing the "lm" model by location, and at the end generating my dataset with all my data + the 2 columns Pedicted and Stud.resid. My issue is that the values generated seem to be ok for the first Location but not for the rest. So, my question : am I using the right code or not?